# How to add values depending on length of an array

Tags: python, arrays

Not sure if I am over thinking this but I have this section of code:

```
struct.pack("b", this_or_address_send_array)
```

This section of code simply creates a packet and populates it with the value of the array, the number of `b` is number of characters in the array list ideally.

I want to have as many b's as I do elements in an array.

So if `len( this_or_address_send_array)` gave me 6 I want:

```
struct.pack("bbbbbb", this_or_address_send_array)
```

What is the most effective way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the format dynamically, according to the length:

```
struct.pack("b" * len(this_or_address_send_array), this_or_address_send_array)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just multiply by the literal `"b"` by the array length

```
"b" * len(this_or_address_send_array)
```

Example:

```
>>> this_or_address_send_array = [5,4,3,3,6,6,2,2,3]
>>> "b" * len(this_or_address_send_array)
'bbbbbbbbb'
```